# If I assign and integer variable the integer 160 and try to store it in a byte variable, why does the value change from 160 to -96?

Tags: java, variables, integer, byte

```
int einInt;
byte einByte;

einInt = 160;
einByte = (byte) einInt;
System.out.println(einByte);
```

// System.out.println(einByte); now outputs -96
// please try to explain this to me as detailed as possible

Comment: You know bytes are signed in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte in Java is an 8-bit signed integer, meaning it has a range of -128...127. 160 falls outside of that range, so it overflows back to the beginning of that range, and it overflows by 33 (160 - 127 = 33). Adding 1 to a byte value of 127 will overflow to -128, but since the overflow was 33, it then adds 32 to -128 which results in -96.

Comment: ooh okay, I wasnt looking at it this way. I though about it in binary and was confused how java cut the value and why it suddenly became a negative value. But I do think I get it now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Java uses two's complement for this if you want to get technical, but it equates to the behavior I described.

Comment: yes thanks, I´ll do some more research on that but you already helped me alot.